# How to trace multiple remotes in one local git repository?

Tags: git

For example, we have a project called `testX`, and multiple git remote

1. git@github.com:AAA/testX.git
2. git@bitbucket.com:BBB/testX.git
3. git@bitbucket.com:CCC/testX2.git

And i have also a remote:

```
git@github.com:DDD/testX.git
```

I want my local git repo looks like

```
local:               remote

master branch ->     git@github.com:DDD/testX.git master 
AAA/master    ->     git@github.com:AAA/testX.git master
BBB/master    ->     git@bitbucket.com:BBB/testX.git master
CCC/master    ->     git@bitbucket.com:CCC/testX2.git master
```

How can do this? and is there anything i should beware?

Comment: Look into `git remote add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

```
git clone git@github.com:DDD/testX.git
```

Then [add your other remotes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html#git-remote-emaddem):

```
git remote add AAA git@github.com:AAA/testX.git
git remote add BBB git@github.com:BBB/testX.git
git remote add CCC git@github.com:CCC/testX.git
```

Finally fetch your remotes:

```
git fetch AAA
git fetch BBB
git fetch CCC
```

A `git branch -avv` should show what you wanted.

Don't forget, with the [Git protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol), you cannot push back to a GitHub repo.

Comment: I don't want to push back to AAA/BBB/CCC(readonly), as long as I can push back to DDD, its fine. does your method work that way?

Comment: For DDD, you need to clone with an https url or an SSH one, if you want to push back to it.